# jQuery limit the results/selection returned

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to limited the results returned in jQuery

```
<body>
  <div id="box">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>        
    </ul>         
  </div>  

  <script>
      $(function(){
          var num = 4;
          console.log( $('#box').children(':first').children(num).text() );
      })
  </script>
</body>
```

This will output:

> `OneTwoThreeFourFiveSix`

But I want:

> `OneTwoThreeFour`

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLqrc/)**: http://jsfiddle.net/JLqrc/

Comment: `$('#box').children(':first').children()[0]` will return the first, `$('#box').children(':first').children()[1]` the second, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `:lt()`

```
$('#box').children(':first').children(':lt('+num+')');
```

or as MackieeE commented to shorten the code

```
$('#box li:lt('+ num +')').text()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G9CVH/1/)

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: Thus can be shortened to: `$('#box li:lt('+ num +')').text()` as personally I'm not sure what's required for `.children(':first')` part

Comment: @MackieeE Yeah you are right, i'll add it to the answer if its ok

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) too,

```
$('#box ul li').slice(0,4).text();
```

This gives you more control over what 4 elements are returned - as you can change it to `.slice(1,4)` and it'll return TwoThreeFourFive etc

Here's an example: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eDZ7k/)

Comment: This is best and has more control +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
      var num = 4;
    console.log($("#box ul li:lt("+num+")" ).text());

  })
```